# Firebase simple user auth rule

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm just starting out with Firebase.

I am using one of the quickstart-js templates.

I'm trying to add a .read security rule so users can only read posts that the created.

I am a bit confused as the rule is passing if I test against `auth.id` but failing if I test against `auth.uid` (I understand that auth.uid is correct).

In the simulator, this rule is failing:

```
{
  "rules": {
   // ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
        "posts": {
      "$post": {
          ".read": "data.child('uid').val() === auth.uid",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the database structure:

```
{
  "posts" : {
    "-KL6ecPO67H5B8SmPHJr" : {
      "body" : "Just testing out the firebase system.",
      "starCount" : 0,
      "title" : "Camp Se has it's first blog post",
      "uid" : "vaZrC0sSdYTiou587IuePVw9uRT2"
    },
    "-KL6fUBOhsc4zosJbwjb" : {
      "body" : "Another post ja ja ja\n",
      "starCount" : 0,
      "title" : "Another post",
      "uid" : "vaZrC0sSdYTiou587IuePVw9uRT2"
    }
  },
  "user-posts" : {
    "vaZrC0sSdYTiou587IuePVw9uRT2" : {
      "-KL6ecPO67H5B8SmPHJr" : {
        "body" : "Just testing out the firebase system.",
        "starCount" : 0,
        "title" : "Camp Se has it's first blog post",
        "uid" : "vaZrC0sSdYTiou587IuePVw9uRT2"
      },
      "-KL6fUBOhsc4zosJbwjb" : {
        "body" : "Another post ja ja ja\n",
        "starCount" : 0,
        "title" : "Another post",
        "uid" : "vaZrC0sSdYTiou587IuePVw9uRT2"
      }
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "vaZrC0sSdYTiou587IuePVw9uRT2" : {
      "email" : "user@gmail.com"
    }
  }
}
```

Simulation Results Details:

```
Simulation results
Type    read
Location    /posts/KL6ecPO67H5B8SmPHJr/
Data    null
Auth    { "provider": "google", "uid": "vaZrC0sSdYTiou587IuePVw9uRT2" }
Admin   false
edit Read denied
close
Line 7 (/posts/KL6ecPO67H5B8SmPHJr)
read: "data.child('uid').val() === auth.uid"
```

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing(tm) to do.

Comment: When you open the Details of the error message, what does it say. That as text too would be more useful than as a screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

I had a mistake in my simulators "Location" field.  When I copied the post id from database I had missed the preceding `-` character.

I fixed this up and the rule works :-)

Comment: Good to hear Tim. I'm going to vote to close your question as a typo, since it's unlikely that people that make the same mistake will find it (because they're not aware of the cause of their problem).